# Me suma el doble de la cantidad a ingresar en java

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, class, collection

Con este método quiero ingresar una cantidad a una cuenta y sumar lo que ya tiene:

```
public boolean ingresoCuenta(double cantidadAIngresar, String ibanAIngresar){
    boolean procesoRealizado = false;
   
    for(int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++){
        if(ibanAIngresar.equalsIgnoreCase(listaClientes.get(i).getIbanCliente())){
            listaClientes.get(i).setSaldoCuenta(listaClientes.get(i).getSaldoCuenta() + cantidadAIngresar);
            procesoRealizado = true;
            break;
        } else{
            procesoRealizado = false;
        }
    }
   
    return procesoRealizado;
}
```

El problema es que en vez de ingresar lo que yo inserto, inserta justamente el doble de la cantidad deseada.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tenía en la clase principal, que estaba llamando dos veces al método. El método está bien realizado.

Un saludo.